# Azure devOps pipeline fails sometime with error The run you are attempting to access is already complete and will not accept new groups

Tags: azure-pipelines, cypress

I've created 2 pipelines (Int Smoke, QA Smoke) in the same branch, those 2 pipelines are triggering from 2 different pipelines. But pipelines are failing sometimes (Int Smoke and QA Smoke).

Pipeline fails with below errors but not every time. I don't run the pipelines at the same time. And no parallel runs.

```
The run you are attempting to access is already complete and will not accept new groups

When a run finishes all of its groups, it waits for a configurable set of time before finally completing. You must add more groups during that time period

The --tag flag you passed was: 
The --group flag you passed was: Azure CI
The --ciBuildId flag you passed was: 20230302.3
```

How to solve this.

Comment: Do they both get the *same* ciBuildId?

Comment: Are you using Cypress? I suspect the error is not from Azure DevOps, but from some other tool...

Comment: See also: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/7865

Comment: Actually they didn't have same buidId, but same buildNumber (Build Name) as I used default name. I changed it and issue got resolved. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved once I changed the buildNumber (build Name).
I used the default name and both pipelines had the same name sometimes and that was the issue here.